# Simple Modal pop up window and ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, simplemodal

I have added ckeditor to a modal pop up window. I'm using http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/ and CKEditor 4.4.6. Also using jquery-1.8.2.

When the pop window is opened a blank text area is displayed. When I navigate to the page, the CKeditor is displayed correctly. Does anyone know how to get the CKEditor to display in a pop up window.

Comment: I got this to work. I had added <script src="~/Content/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script> to both the home layout page and the pop up form. I removed the script tag from the home layout page and the editor was displayed in the pop up form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work. I had added  to both the home layout page and the pop up form. I removed the script tag from the home layout page and the editor was displayed in the pop up form.